# Installing Java on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, java

I am very new to Ubuntu and trying to install java on Ubuntu 20.04. I follow the instructions on https://tecadmin.net/install-java-ubuntu-20-04/ and at about 2% progress the license agreement pops up but won't let me continue. There is  but clicking on it does nothing. Scrolling down to the bottom I see nothing else I can click on to allow it to continue.

Answer (score 2):

The license agreement comes from the Oracle Java 14 package, not the Ubuntu Java 14 package. Use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys to accept the license in the Oracle license agreement window that pops up.

---

There is no license agreement for the Ubuntu version of openjdk-14-jdk.  Remove the non-default software sources from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017/) and run `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available software.

Now you are ready to install Java. To manually download and install openjdk-14-jdk alongside openjdk-8-jdk and openjdk-11-jdk in Ubuntu 20.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-11-jdk
cd ~/Desktop/
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-14/openjdk-14-jre-headless_14.0.2+12-1_amd64.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-14/openjdk-14-jre_14.0.2+12-1_amd64.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-14/openjdk-14-jdk-headless_14.0.2+12-1_amd64.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-14/openjdk-14-jdk_14.0.2+12-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./openjdk-14-jre-headless_14.0.2+12-1_amd64.deb ./openjdk-14-jre_14.0.2+12-1_amd64.deb ./openjdk-14-jdk-headless_14.0.2+12-1_amd64.deb ./openjdk-14-jdk_14.0.2+12-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still stops at  the license agreement and clicking ok does nothing.

Comment: There is no license agreement for the Ubuntu version of openjdk-14-jdk. Get rid of the non-default software sources in your sources.list file with [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017/) and run `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available software.

Comment: I think OP is trying to install Oracle's Java 14. @Dave Can you please share a screenshot?

Comment: I think the OP is trying to install Oracle's Java 14 and is being victimized by Oracle's grasping Microsoft-liike manipulation instead of virtuously installing the Ubuntu Java 14 package.

Comment: Oracle Technology Network License Agreement for Oracle Java SE              
 │                                                                             
 │                                                                             
 │                                                                             
 │ You MUST agree to the license available in                                  
 │ https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/javase-lice    
 │ nse.html if you want to install Oracle JDK.

Comment: Oracle is willing to authorize Your access to software associated with      
 │ this License Agreement (“Agreement”) only upon the condition that You       
 │ accept that this Agreement governs Your use of the software. By             
 │ selecting the "Accept License Agreement" button or box (or the              
 │ equivalent) or installing or using the Programs, You indicate Your          
 │                                                                             
 │                                  <Ok>

Comment: @Dave Seems you're stuck on accepting the licence and unable to figure out the way to accept that. Press <Tab> to select "<OK>" and then press <Enter>.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) which gives you more flexibility down the line.

Directions are quite simple:

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

from there `sdk ls` will show you available packages and `sdk install java` will install Java.  Of course, there many options, those are just defaults to point you in another direction than.

I believe it's possible to use Oracle binaries with `sdkman` but would have to delve deeper into their documentation.  The above options use open source repositories, so the licensing is [very easy](https://zulu.org/) to deal with.