# What is the highest JDK which is compatible with Netbeans 12?

Tags: software-installation, java, snap, netbeans, ide

running `java -version` shows:

```
openjdk version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu14.29+23-CA (build 14.0.2+12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu14.29+23-CA (build 14.0.2+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

([Installed](https://askubuntu.com/a/1264379/847449) the Java JDK with `sdkman`.)

Before I install Netbeans with `snap` do I need to configure anything else to ensure that Netbeans uses `JDK 14`?

Comment: The latest stable version of the netbeans snap package is netbeans 12.0 which as its version suggests targets Java 12.

Comment: oh.  so it won't work nicely with Java greater than 12 then?

Comment: Java 14 might be able to work in NetBeans 12 the ugly way.